# How can I get access to the index of the highlighted dataset in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to display a value (Prod_ary[1](https://jsfiddle.net/tL8vo3zo/4/)[selected index of chart] in the tool tips using the beforeBody callback:

```
tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: true,
    callbacks: {
        beforeBody: function(tooltipItems, data){
            return 'Count:  ' + "<display Prod_ary[1][highlighted index]";
        },

        label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
            return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': '  + TS_ary[tooltipItems.datasetIndex][tooltipItems.index];

        }
}
```

I have attempted to access the index to tell me which element I need to display in the array using:

```
return 'Count:  ' + Prod_ary[1][tooltipItems.index];
```

But it returns undefined.  I'm screwing something up but can't quite figure out what.
[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL8vo3zo/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tooltips callbacks I changed this:

```
return 'Count:  ' + Prod_ary[1][tooltipItems.index];
```

to this:

```
return 'Count:  ' + Prod_ary[1][tooltipItems[0]["index"]];
```